# Meaning of סוף (suf) = weed/reed vs edge/end

Tags: words, hebrew, tanach

What is the original meaning of the word

## סף

and its cognate

## סוף

?

We know that **סף** in the Bible means edge or threshold.

But why does its cognate **סוף**
carry the meaning of
*weed* or *reed*
most of the time but the meaning of *end* just five times in the Bible, and even then only in the latter books?

We know that in Zohar **אין סוף** means *without end*.

How does/did *edge* get inflected or derived into *weed* or *reed*?

The sea which Moses and Israel had crossed while being pursued by the Pharoah, is called

## ים סוף

Therefore consequently, is that sea actually named

- sea of weeds/reeds
- or sea at the edge/end (of land)
  ?

What is the actual intended meaning of the word when Ezekiel is told to measure the temple's dimension with a **סף** ? Does Qabalah theses on **אין סוף** make any implication upon the **סף** that Ezekiel is told to use to measure the temple's dimension?

Comment: Are you only asking about the meaning of the word in Ezekiel, or about the words meaning in general? The latter would probably be off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The Yam Suph (mentioned in the Torah) clearly means the sea of reeds not the sea at the edge. The word סוף when pronounced like *suph* always means reeds and never connotes edge. (see Isaiah 19:6). In Parshat Shmot 2:3-6 too the word *suph* means reeds. (It says that the daughter of Pharaoh saw Moses in the *Suph* (בתוך הסוף) which clearly means "between the reeds of the sea". See also verse 3 (וַתָּשֶׂם בַּסּוּף עַל שְׂפַת הַיְאֹר) where it clearly reads "between the reeds on the edge of the Nile"). It is reasonable to assume that the word *suph* mentioned in chapter 2 has the same meaning as the one in chapter 10 and 13. (The reed was also a common used grass in Egypt and indigenous to the area, so most likely it was the same weed found near the Nile that was also found near the Yam suph).

Some scholars even think that the word *suph* used in sefer Shmot is an egyptian loan word (*twf* in egyptian hieroglyphics http://www.biblearchaeology.org/post/2008/08/New-Evidence-from-Egypt-on-the-Location-of-the-Exodus-Sea-Crossing-Part-I.aspx). On the other hand, The word סוף which is pronounced like *soph* meaning edge or end did not exist, as part of the Hebrew language, until much later. The first instance it is used in the context of edge/end is in Kohelet 3:11; 7:2.

As for how the word *suph* (reeds) evoloved into *soph* (edge/end) it is not so clear, but some suggest that that "After this event at Yam Suph, perhaps the verb Soph, meaning "destroy" and "come to an end," originated". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yam_Suph. It is also possible that they are two different words altogether and bear no relation to each other though their roots are very similar.

Hope this helps.